# Probability theory (heads and tails)

Tags: probability

A coin was tossed $N$ times. The number of heads is 10% more than the number of tails. At what $N$ can we say that the coin is "dishonest" (heads and tails fall out with different probability)?

Comment: It depends on how confident you want to be. This is veering into statistics.

Comment: We can never be sure that we have a non-fair coin. It depends on the fallacy probability we choose for a hypothesis test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample size for a dichotomous variable with $p$ proportion of success:

$$N = p(1-p)\bigg({Z \over E}\bigg)^2$$

where,

$Z$ is the $z$-value corresponding to your confidence interval (eg. $z$-value $1.96$ for $95\%$ confidence interval),

$E$ is the margin of error (eg: $0.05$ for $5\%$ MoE)

For the given example, let $p$ be the proportion of tails.

$$\therefore 1 - p = 1.1 \times p$$
$$\implies 1 = 2.1p \implies p = {10 \over 21}$$

Substituting, we get

$$N = \bigg({10 \over 21}\bigg)\bigg(1 - {10 \over 21}\bigg)\bigg({1.96 \over 0.05}\bigg)^2 = 383.28 \approx 384$$

So, 384 trials will tell you with 5% margin of error in 95% Confidence Interval.
This will change if you change your CI and margin of error parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it's the right reasoning.